# Android Studio Update 0.4.0 could not find buildConfig()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After upgrading Android Studio to version 0.4.0 I got a new error:

I upgraded to gradle 1.9 via the gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

and upgraded the gradle version in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
}
```

Now my project is building again.

I have some String constants defined for different productFlavors:

```
productFlavors {
    local {
        buildConfig "public static final String MY_KEY = \"\";"
    }

    alpha {
        buildConfig "public static final String MY_KEY = \"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\";"
    }

    beta {
        buildConfig "public static final String MY_KEY = \"YYYYY-YYYYY-YYY\";"
    }
}
```

And here is the new error

> **Could not find method buildConfig() for arguments** [public static final String MY_KEY = "";] on GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated{name=local, minSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=-1, renderscriptTargetApi=-1, renderscriptSupportMode=null, renderscriptNdkMode=null, versionCode=-1, versionName=null, packageName=null, testPackageName=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null}.

Everything was working with Android Studio 3.7

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I can't use the comment (too long).
You can find it in the what's new in gradle 1.9.

> DSL Changes: `buildConfigLine` is replaced by `buildConfigField`:
>
> ```
> buildConfigField "boolean", "MY_FLAG", "true"
> ```
>
> You can override fields defined in default config in flavors or build types. See 'basic' sample.
>
> Build Config also now automatically contain more constants for `PACKAGE_NAME`, `VERSION_CODE`, `VERSION_NAME`, `BUILD_TYPE`, `FLAVOR` as well as `FLAVOR_<group>` if there are several flavor dimensions.

So if you have a line like this:

```
buildConfig "public static final boolean MY_FLAG = true;"
```

You should now replace it for something like this:

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "MY_FLAG", "true"
```

In your case:

```
buildConfigField "String" , "MY_KEY" ,  "\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""
```

**UPDATE 12/09/2015:**

With the new **experimental plugin** (0.2.1) you have to use:

```
buildConfigFields.with {
                create() {
                    type = "String"
                    name = "MY_KEY"
                    value = "MY_VALUE"
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your help! works fine. here are some additional infos https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/2XCHLizKpWs

Comment: So how do I access **BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE**?  I don't get it.

Answer (score 3):

This version introduces a change:

```
buildConfigField "<type>", "<name>", "<value>"
```

If you have a line like this:

```
buildConfig "public static final boolean FLAG = true;"
```

Now you have to use:

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "FLAG", "true"
```

For String values you can use:

```
buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"foo\""
```

note:
The previous DSL proprety:

```
buildConfigLine "<value>"
```

has changed to

```
buildConfigField "<type>", "<name>", "<value>"
```