# Gradle script not working since 0.4.0 - Could not find method plus()

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have some product flavors set up and I used some scripting to add/modify some static variables depending on the selected flavor:

```
def createStaticVariable(name, value) {
    return "public final static String " + name + " = \"" + value + "\";"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    productFlavors {
        // DEV
        devtest {
            packageName "com.sample.dev.test"
            buildConfig += createStaticVariable("API_URL", "http://sample.com/")
            buildConfig += createStaticVariable("API_URL_IMAGE", "http://static.sample.com/")
            // some more...
        }
    }
}
```

That gradle build script worked without issues on 0.3.7 but with 0.4.0 and the Gradle 1.9 update it stopped working and throws the following error message:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ProjectName'.
Could not find method plus() for arguments [public final static String API_URL = "http://sample.com/";]
on GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated{name=buildConfig, minSdkVersion=-1, targetSdkVersion=-1, renderscriptTargetApi=-1, renderscriptSupportMode=null, renderscriptNdkMode=null, versionCode=-1, versionName=null, packageName=null, testPackageName=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null}.
```

I figured out that `+` itself works when I just use it with `"string" + "string"` but not in combination with my method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround by replacing my method with the `debugConfigField` built in method I found [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678232/180538).

So `buildConfig += createStaticVariable("API_URL", "http://sample.com/")` should be `buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "http://sample.com/"`

Comment: This is not really a workaround. We changed the DSL to make it possible to override fields. For instance you could define a default value in `defaultConfig { ... }` and then override it  in only one of the flavors or build types.

Comment: @XavierDucrohet ok but I don't really get why I get the error message I posted in the question in the first place...

Comment: I think it's just Gradle being a bit confusing (it happens). `GroupableProductFlavorDsl_Decorated` is the class of the devtest object. It should mention that it doesn't find `buildConfig` property on the object instead. Might be good to report that to gradle devs.