# How to define multiple common sources

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to create the following project structure with gradle

```
FlavorA
     java
        sources
FlavorB
     java
        sources
FlavorC
     java
        sources
main
     java
        sources
commonCodeWithFlavorAAndB
      java
        sources
commonCodeWithFlavorAAndC
      java
        sources
```

now I created this project structure, and defined the sourceSet srcDirs in build.gradle

however, when i try to run flavorA it says a class from commonCodeWithFlavorAAndC is missing to run A

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an error in refactoring.
When I split the files into different implementations, it for some reason changed the package name of the given file in the FlavorAAndC folder,
even though it was on the same path `folderx/foldery/file`
the top line of "package" said "`folderx.foldery.folderz?!.file`"

Answer (score 1):

When you create different flavors it has two aspects to deal with

1. res folder
2. java files

   - With res folder, you can actually have same file in main, FlavorA ,... Android will automatically MERGE it.
   - With java files, the classes canNOT be merged. It can only be replaced.

See this for better understanding

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710180/1852441

Ie. In order to override a class called Activity1.java (for instance), you will have to **remove it from main folder and provide each flavor with Activity1.java.**

That is why the compiler says it is missing a class.

Comment: This answer does not help me unfortunately,
I did remove the file from main, I have files in FlavorA and commonAAndC, but it says the file in commonAAndC is missing