# Android Studio - Alpha, Beta and production Release

Tags: android

I am working in one of the project currently. And I want to release it on play store my question is can I have same apk which have Alpha, Beta and production flavors which can be changed dynamically on the basis of current configuration of play store. I don't want to upload different apk in play store.

This is the procedure I want to follow:

Will upload one apk in alpha which points to alpha url 
when it is tested I push same to beta which automatically points to beta url
when it is tested and final , I will push the same apk to production without generating or uploading new one.

Is this possible in android studio.

Comment: refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698863/build-flavors-for-different-version-of-same-class. If you have alpha , beta or production url in any .java constant file then keep that file same like this link.