# Use different class for android build variant

Tags: android

I have 6 apps that all use one main build to run off of. They all have 4 tab buttons but I'd like to switch one app to have 5 tab bar buttons.

So I've configured a main class that has 4 tab bar buttons, however for one app I'd like it to override that and use 5 tab bar buttons. I'm just not sure how to change out the classes.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: also, if you downvote, please say why. If it's unclear what I'm asking or if it's a simple question etc.

Here's the class I'm trying to exchange

```
package com.android.stanby.app.domain;

import com.android.stanby.app.R;

/**
 * Created by trevor.wood on 2018/05/01.
 */

public class BottomMenuButtons {

    public static final int TAB_INDEX_JOB_LIST = 0;
    public static final int TAB_INDEX_JOB_MAP = 1;
    public static final int TAB_INDEX_WEB = 2;
    public static final int TAB_INDEX_RECOMMEND = 3;
    public static final int TAB_INDEX_CHAT = 4;

    public static final int[] NAVI_ITEMS = {
            R.id.bottom_navigation_job_list,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_job_map,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_keep,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_recommend,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_chat,
    };
    public static final int[] NAVI_ICONS = {
            R.id.bottom_navigation_job_list_icon,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_job_map_icon,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_keep_icon,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_recommend_icon,
            R.id.bottom_navigation_chat_icon,
    };
    public static final int[] NAVI_OFF_ICONS = {
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_job_off,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_job_map_off,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_keep_off,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_recommend_off,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_chat_off,
    };
    public static final int[] NAVI_ON_ICONS = {
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_job_on,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_job_map_on,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_keep_on,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_recommend_on,
            R.drawable.stanby_ic_bottom_tab_chat_on,
    };
}
```

And here are my build settings

```
def PACKAGE_NAME = "com.stanby.jp"
// VERSION_CODE及びVERSION_NAMEはgradle.propertiesに定義されている
def VERSION_CODE = APP_VERSION_CODE.toInteger()
def VERSION_NAME = APP_VERSION_NAME

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode VERSION_CODE
        versionName VERSION_NAME
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias STANBY_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword STANBY_KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file(System.getenv("HOME") + "/.android/" + STANBY_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword STANBY_STORE_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    // フレーバー
    flavorDimensions "type", "env"
    productFlavors {
        // 全部入り
        stanby {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}"
        }

        // アルバイト・パート
        part {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.part"
        }

        // 転職（正社員）
        full {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.full"
        }

        // ハローワーク
        hellowork {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.hellowork"
        }

        // 富山県
        toyama {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.toyama"
        }

        // 福島県
        fukushima {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.fukushima"
        }

        // 福岡県
        fukuoka {
            dimension "type"
            applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.fukuoka"
        }

        develop {
            dimension "env"
        }
        product {
            dimension "env"
        }
    }

    // ビルドタイプ
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }
        debug {
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }

    // ソース構成
    sourceSets {
        // 全部入り
        stanby {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/stanby/java', 'src/common/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/stanby/res', 'src/common/res']
        }

        // アルバイト・パート
        part {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/part/java', 'src/common/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/part/res', 'src/common/res']
        }

        // 転職（正社員）
        full {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/full/java', 'src/common/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/full/res', 'src/common/res']
        }

        // ハローワーク
        hellowork {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/hellowork/java', 'src/common/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/hellowork/res', 'src/common/res']
        }

        // 富山県
        toyama {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/toyama/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/toyama/res']
        }

        // 福島県
        fukushima {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/fukushima/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/fukushima/res']
        }

        // 福岡県
        fukuoka {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/fukuoka/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/fukuoka/res']
        }

        // 検証環境
        develop {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/develop/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/develop/res']
        }

        // 本番環境
        product {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/product/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/product/res']
        }
    }

    // google-services.json を develop/product からコピーする
    gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
        if (task.name ==~ /process.*GoogleServices/) {
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if (task.name ==~ /(?i)process${variant.name}GoogleServices/) {
                    String fromDir = "${variant.flavorName}";
                    if (fromDir.endsWith("Develop")) {
                        fromDir = "develop";

                    } else if (fromDir.endsWith("Product")) {
                        fromDir = "product";
                    }
                    print "\n#####################################################\n";
                    print "google-services.json fromDir=${fromDir}\n"
                    print "#####################################################\n\n";

                    copy {
                        from "src/" + fromDir
                        into "."
                        include "google-services.json"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
    def supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    // https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases
    def playServiceVersion = '11.8.0'
    // https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android
    def firebaseUiDatabaseVersion = '1.2.0'

    def retrofitVersion = '2.1.0'
    def okHttpVersion = '3.4.1'
    def daggerVersion = '2.6'
    def butterknifeVersion = '8.3.0'
    def rxLifecycleVersion = '0.7.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // 計測
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.2.1'

    // support library
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"

    // Play service
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

    // Firebase
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:${playServiceVersion}"
    compile "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:${firebaseUiDatabaseVersion}"

    // retrofit
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:${retrofitVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"

    // okHttp
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpVersion}"

    // Glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    // Twillio
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'

    // 求人詳細の WebView レイアウト
    compile 'com.samskivert:jmustache:1.12'

    // base framework
    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknifeVersion"
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknifeVersion"

    compile "com.trello:rxlifecycle:$rxLifecycleVersion"
    compile "com.trello:rxlifecycle-android:$rxLifecycleVersion"
    compile "com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:$rxLifecycleVersion"
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

    // library
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
    compile 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2'

    // test
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    }
    androidTestCompile("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:$retrofitVersion") {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: "I'd like it to override ...". Not sure if you can have 4 product flavors sharing same class with 4 buttons and one product flavor with different class having 5 buttons. I would say that 4 button class has to copied into each of 4 flavors and flavor5 will have different implementation with class having 5 buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your flavor directory for it. For example, if you want to create specific class for `fukusima` flavor, you need to create the `fukusima` directory inside your `src` directory. Like this:

```
src/fukusima/java/your/package/name/bottommenu
```

then you create the `BottomMenuButtons` there. Change `your/package/name/bottommenu` to your `BottomMenuButtons` path.

The other way is using a flag for adding specific flag for your flavor. First, add a specific flag to your flavor. For example, we use `USE_FIVE_TAB`. Change the flavor by adding the flag:

```
productFlavors {
    stanby {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_FIVE_TAB", "false"
        dimension "type"
        applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}"
    }
    part {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_FIVE_TAB", "false"
        dimension "type"
        applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.part"
    }

    full {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_FIVE_TAB", "true"
        dimension "type"
        applicationId "${PACKAGE_NAME}.full"
    }

    // add the same flag to all of your flavors
    ...
```

Then, you can use it something like this:

```
if(BuildConfig.USE_FIVE_TAB) {
   // set to use five tabs
} else {
   // use four tabs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override classses per variant by creating the corresponding folder in the project with the same name for the flavor. Check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698863/build-flavors-for-different-version-of-same-class) that explains the directory structure needed. Then automatically when you compile that flavor the class will be overriden.