# How to build different flavor apks with different Java code?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I know we can build different flavor apks with different resources by creating different directory within src, but now I want to make some java code customized, is that possible? Or any other ways to do it?

---

update

I have a project with 100 *.java files, and I have 10 flavors, but each flavor has only one file is customized and the file in each flavor is not the same file, so I have to put that 10 files in each flavor, and once a file in that 10 files is modified, I will have to modify the same file in other flavors, the project is like:

`+ App
|- src
    |- main
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java(can't be here)
             |- B.java(can't be here)
             |- C.java(can't be here)
             |- D.java(can't be here)
             |- E.java(can't be here)
             |- F.java(can't be here)
             |- G.java(can't be here)
             |- Others.java
      + res
   |- flavorA 
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java(customized)
             |- B.java
             |- C.java
             |- D.java
             |- E.java
             |- F.java
             |- G.java
      + res
    |- flavorB 
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java(customized)
             |- C.java
             |- D.java
             |- E.java
             |- F.java
             |- G.java
      + res
    |- flavorC 
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java
             |- C.java(customized)
             |- D.java
             |- E.java
             |- F.java
             |- G.java
      + res
    |- flavorD
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java
             |- C.java
             |- D.java(customized)
             |- E.java
             |- F.java
             |- G.java
      + res
    |- flavorE
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java
             |- C.java
             |- D.java
             |- E.java(customized)
             |- F.java
             |- G.java
      + res
    |- flavorF
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java
             |- C.java
             |- D.java
             |- E.java
             |- F.java(customized)
             |- G.java
      + res
    |- flavorG
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java
             |- C.java
             |- D.java
             |- E.java
             |- F.java
             |- G.java(customized)
      + res`

Comment: What do you mean by "java code customized"?

Comment: checkout : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710180/5906447

Comment: @PankajKumar means there are some Customization.java files needed to be customized

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use different java class for both different product flavor so your project structurer will be like below image.

[image]

It was works for me.

```
+ App
|- src
    |- main
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java
             |- B.java
             |- C.java
             |- D.java
             |- E.java
             |- F.java
             |- G.java
             |- Others.java
      + res
   |- flavorA 
      |- java
          |- path
             |- A.java(customized)
      + res
    |- flavorB 
      |- java
          |- path
             |- B.java(customized)
      + res
    |- flavorC 
      |- java
          |- path
             |- C.java(customized)
      + res
    |- flavorD
      |- java
          |- path
             |- D.java(customized)
      + res
    |- flavorE
      |- java
          |- path
             |- E.java(customized)
      + res
    |- flavorF
      |- java
          |- path
             |- F.java(customized)
      + res
    |- flavorG
      |- java
          |- path
             |- G.java(customized)
      + res
```

You have to add file structure as above. You have to add all the files on main directory and only you need to add modified files as per flavor. If you will put every files in every flavor than in future when you will change A.java than you have to update every A.java of all flavors.

**So its better add all the files on main directory and only you need to add modified files as per flavor**.

Comment: In this way, AdminHelperImpl.java can not be put in 'main' ,and if I have 10 flavors, I will have to maintain 10 AdminHelperImpl.java files

Comment: yes if your all the java files different from each other than you have to manage every file. Just for example if you have 5 files same and other 5 are the different than you have to add Sample.java (same files)in main folder and other five you have to add as per your flavours.

Comment: @jason.yu  Did you get that ?

Comment: I get it ,but what I mean is that there are more flavors and more different Customization.java files  in different flavors ,look what I have updated in my question

Comment: Actually, the file structure in your answer is what I want, but it will build failed, did you successfully run it ?

Comment: Did you solve this issue you are still getting issue ?

Comment: I use another work around way to do it ,which is to add a common code module to put the same files, and all modules not customed  declare "srcDir codeModule" to add those files,only the customed files are put in the customer flavors