# Creating Predefined class like BuildConfig in gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to define and create custom classes in gradle to define some constants values for my projects.

We can define field under the BuildConfig as above

```
buildConfigField "String", 'SOME_FIELD', 'SOME_VALUE'
```

But I need another object not related or under the BuildConfig. And I want to use java/kotlin code. The output that I want like above.

```
public final class SomeClass {
    public static final String SOME_FIELD = "SOME_VALUE";
}
```

Is this possible to create class like that ?

Comment: Why do you need to define a custom class in gradle? You can just define the class in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: I need this class why we need BuildConfig. It will have some logic depending gradle settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build flavors for different version of same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698863/build-flavors-for-different-version-of-same-class)

Comment: Nope, I totaly want a different class. Neither bound to flavors nor build types.

Comment: If not bound to flavor or build types, what is this class dependent on that you need it in a gradle file? The clearer you can be about what you're actually trying to achieve, the better odds you have of getting an answer.